# select master with details fileds in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I want to select some of the Product's information after Category's infromation using linq to objects.

```
 var test = Context.Categories.Select(t => new { t.CategoryID, t.CategoryName });
```

How can i select Product's information.
Category and Products have one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Why can't you use Context.Products.Where(x => x.CategoryId = requiredCategoryId)?

Comment: i dont have any predicate and i want to select all categories with name of the products

Comment: And what is the result supposed to look like? (the resulting type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer , i use SelectMany() like this:

```
 var test = Context.Categories.SelectMany(t=>t.Products).Select(t => new { t.CategoryID, t.Category.CategoryName,t.ProductName });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using LINQ query syntax as well

```
var test = from c in Context.Categories
           from p in c.Products
           select new { c.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, p.ProductName });
```

Behind the scenes this is synonymous to :

```
var test = Categories.SelectMany
(
   c => c.Products, 
   (c, p) => new
   {
      c.CategoryID,
      c.CategoryName,
      p.ProductName
   }
);
```